# JFrog CLI specifiy download path for downloaded artifacts

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Right now i am working with the JFrog CLI.
The JFrog CLI documentation is good but not the best one.
I wanted to specify the destination path for the downloaded artifacts from the JFrog Artifactory.

`jfrog.exe rt search --user=someUser --password=somePassword --url="https://someUrl" --props "someKey=someValue" REPOPATH/`

This is my command line and i wanted to add the destination path.
The goal is to change the harddrive and download it there but right now its downloading to the folder where the `JFrog.exe` is starting and this is the problem.
Thanks

Comment: Anyone any ideas?

Comment: why are you using the search command if you want to download?
In the CLI's download command you have to specify the "Target path" which (if i understand your question correctly) is what you're after. check the CLI documentation for downloading, and view the command arguments:   https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles

Comment: Sorry I wrote the wrong command but the command above searches for an artefact which will be downloaded afterwards if found.I looked up in the documentary of JFrog CLI commands and found the Target Path but the problem is , you can't specify other hard drives as Target Path and i wanted to know if it's somehow possible to download to a specific target.

Comment: Try to append destination path at the end. `jfrog rt dl --user xxx --password xxx -url xxx --flat=true xxx/xxx/test.zip test/` it will download test.zip into test folder.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible (and you can specify other drives as the target drive as you asked).

For example, if I want to download all files from the repository "generic-local" in Artifactory to the folder called "local" on the Z: drive of my Windows machine, I can do that using a spec file

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "generic-local/",
            "target": "z:/local/"
        }
    ]
}
```

After that, I can call the command with `jfrog rt dl --spec <name of the specfile>`

The same would work with spec vars to make it more configurable, in which case my spec file would be

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "generic-local/",
            "target": "${tgt}"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the command would be `jfrog rt dl --spec <name of the specfile> --spec-vars tgt=z:/local/`

Comment: Can be done without a separate file? According to docs this should just be a param.